# How can i show message before that the user close the app in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, chromebook

[image]I have a flutter app that i published on play store. I download it on my acer chromebook and i see the window bar. I want to show a message when the user want to close the app by clicking on the X of the window bar. How can i do this in flutter?

Comment: is this android app or desktop app?

Comment: it's an android app but downloaded on an acer chromeBook

Comment: try `PopScope` that might help you. i don't know how the flutter app work on chomebook

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the existing [flutter_window_close](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_window_close) package. Check out the example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_window_close/example).

This gives you the possibility to pop a confirmation to the user, and it works on Linux, windows, MacOS.

The is also this [bitsdojo_window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window) which gives you the possibility to customize your windows, manage confirmation dialog on app close button press and more...

Comment: i tried to use **flutter_window_close** but i have this error 
'I/flutter ( 7737): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method init on channel flutter_window_close)'

I think it's because it is not windows or macOs it's a chromeOs

Comment: Try to close the app and run it again. You can run those commands **flutter clean**,  after that, delete **pubspec.lock** and run again **flutter pub get**. Most of the time it works